# Enabling a "Remember Me" or Non-Logout for Chrome Extensions

Tags: authentication, google-chrome-extension, remember-me

I am building a chrome extension for the first time. One issue I keep coming across is every 24 hours it logs me out. I have to re-login and I have no idea if there is a "remember me" or a keep me logged in for more than 24 hours settings? I can't seem to find any documentation on how to support a user being kept logged into the extension.

I have other Chrome Extensions that don't require this re-logging in behavior (for instance my Dropbox extension doesn't do this). Is there some other auth mechanism happening behind the scenes?

Also in the Chrome Extension I can't have it auto-populate with something like last pass, so its annoying for users who have complex passwords having to login every 24 hours.

Comment: There's no such setting or feature in the extensions API. It's something specific to the service/extension.

Comment: What do you mean by that, how is it that my Dropbox Chrome Extension never asks me to log back in but the extension I've been playing with every day asks me to log back in.

Comment: The explanation is still the same. I don't know how to rephrase it better. If you add [MCVE](/help/mcve) maybe we can find a solution/workaround.

Comment: How does Dropbox accomplish it, making it so my account doesn't need constant relogin. Is it the way im building my app with the Auth method?

Comment: Since it's not a part of the extensions API, you'll have to find out the difference e.g. inspect its code in devtools as well as check the network request it makes.